# Stored procedure keeps returning zeros for every table. Where Clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SSIS].[usp_LifeCount]
AS
BEGIN

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Clear the table to prevent duplicate data.
TRUNCATE TABLE SSIS.LivingMales
-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO SSIS.LivingMales
(Males)
SELECT COUNT(SEX)
FROM SSIS.Marvels
WHERE (ALIVE = 'Living Character' AND SEX = 'Male Character');


-- Clear the table to prevent duplicate data.
TRUNCATE TABLE SSIS.LivingFemales
-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO SSIS.LivingFemales
(Females)
SELECT COUNT(SEX)
FROM SSIS.Marvels
WHERE (ALIVE = 'Living Character' AND SEX = 'Female Character');

-- Clear the table to prevent duplicate data.
TRUNCATE TABLE SSIS.DeadMales
-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO SSIS.DeadMales
(Males)
SELECT COUNT(SEX)
FROM SSIS.Marvels
WHERE (ALIVE = 'Deceased Character' AND SEX = 'Male Character');

-- Clear the table to prevent duplicate data.
TRUNCATE TABLE SSIS.DeadFemales
-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO SSIS.DeadFemales
(Females)
SELECT COUNT(SEX)
FROM SSIS.Marvels
WHERE (ALIVE = 'Deceased Character' AND SEX = 'Female Character'); 
END
```

I'm trying to get a total count of how many male/ female characters are alive as well as deceased. I know it's my where clause. When I take them out it returns the total for all and not individual.  Alive is a column name in SSIS.Marvels

Comment: You have determined the problem is your where clause. So you will need to adjust your where clause so that it is correct. We can't possibly tell you what it should be as we don't know your data.

Comment: Outside of your SP, do you get results for `SELECT 
COUNT(SEX) FROM SSIS.Marvels WHERE (ALIVE = 'Living Character' AND SEX = 'Male Character');`?

Comment: This is a really terrible way to get this info. Truncating a table that has only totals, and where you have one table per `ALIVE` status and `SEX`?, this should be a simple query to the first table with a `GROUP BY`

Comment: Seems a bit overkill to have 4 tables to store these 4 values, with the right index the query `SELECT Sex, Alive, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM SSIS.Marvels GROUP BY Sex, Alive` would be very fast, and seems easier to work with, and since you don't need a where clause, you can't have mistakes in it.

Comment: It has to be in a stored procedure and must follow the same pattern I did in SSIS. The Alive colum and Sex Column are both in SSIS.Marvels and the data in them are strings. (Alive column) has either "Deceased Character" or "Living Character" and (SEX Column) has either "Male Character" or "Female Character". I am just showing how many females are alive as well as males and those that are deceased.

Answer (score 0):

Run this to see what your data actually looks like first.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ALIVE, SEX FROM SSIS.Marvels
```

Then you can fix your where clauses to match your data. We can't really fix them for you as we don't know what your data looks like.